# Search by input select

Tags: php, html

How can i search on my site like this; if visitor select input as a username, the table only show that username or id or sex which he write.

I think i should add something instead of * but icouldnt find. would you help me?

```
foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM uyeler ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 20') as $row)
```

Thanks

```
<div class="body">
<div class="table"

        <select>
          <option value="id">ID</option>
          <option value="user">Username</option>
          <option value="sex">Sex</option>
          <option value="country">Country</option>            
          <option value="age">Age</option>
          <option value="twitter">Twitter</option>
          <option value="instagram">Instagram</option>            
          <option value="snapchat">Snapchat</option>
       </select>
            <input type="text" name="searchbox">
            <input type="submit" value="Search"><input type="submit" value="Refresh"></br></br>

        <table align=center width="1200">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Sex</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Twitter</th>
            <th>Instagram</th>
            <th>Snapchat</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        foreach($db->query('SELECT * FROM uyeler ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 20') as $row) {
                echo "<tr><td>" .$row['id'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['username'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['sex'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['country'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['age'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['twitter'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['instagram'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['snapchat'] . "</td>";
                echo ('<td><a href="details.php?id=' .$row['id'] . '" title="Panel">Details</a></td>');
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>

</table>
</div>
```

Comment: What is my mistake in this code? Would you help me?   

What is my mistake in this code? Would you help me?
`foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM uyeler WHERE '{$_POST[arama1]}' = '{$_POST[arama]}' ORDER BY RAND()LIMIT 20") as $row)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the fields from the table, you need the `*`. However you should use `WHERE username = '{$username}'` at the end of your query to limit the results to the requested username only.

If there are multiple criteria, get the keys and values from your `$_GET` or `$_POST` request, and do something like `WHERE {$key1} = '{$val1}' AND {$key2} = '{$val2}'` etc. for your `WHERE` clause. Use `AND` if all conditions must apply, and use `OR` if any condition qualifies for a match.

Be sure to sanitize the incoming username request before you plug it into your query. Also sanitize the keys (best to check against a predefined list), that's another vector for SQL injections in this case.

Comment: When you are only doing "SELECT" queries and don't change any server state, odds are you *don't* do a POST but a GET, because the request is both safe and idempotent. Check [rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) for a firm understanding of http... Using GET for searches makes it possible for a user to bookmark searches.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Wesseling, an informative read. There are of course cases where only retrieval is done, but POST may still be the preferred method in spite of what is implied by GET and POST; and again, there are cases where GET may be a preferred way to trigger a change in the server state. But yea, good point on standard practice. Will conform. Even just over sheer liking for the word `idempotence`. :D